# EntityManager.createNamedQuery(...) doesn't work

Tags: jpa, named-query

I have defined a  NamedNativeQuery next to a lot of `NamedQueries`. With `NamedQueries` the `EntityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName)` works well but when using the `NamedNATIVEQuery` I get an exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: myNamedNativeQueryName not found.

The query itself works well executed in MySql Workbench but defining it as a NamedNativeQuery:

```
@NamedNativeQueries(value = {
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = findVehicleTracksByUuidAndTimerange, query="...", resultClass=myType.class)
})
```

the exception occurs. I try to run the query this way:

```
try {
        List<E> resultList = new ArrayList<E>();
        javax.persistence.Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName, type);
} catch(...)
```

What can be the reason? 
As I already stated: The code from above runs well with dozens of NamedQueries...but suddenly not with the NamedNativeQuery.

Comment: and where is the precise code where you try to access it ? and what is the stack trace of the exception? and the JPA implementation is ? createNamedQuery "works" when I use it with the JPA implementation I use

Comment: How does the query look like?